# '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' in search view Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I just found that error yesterday I don't know what happend everthing was working just fine until I full testing the website

```
TypeError at /home/search_view/
'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/search_view/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=MzGKJGMz7C3uoJgFIILHdZcaLihBfOHQbLGNzyEi9X0HzptGqNbOREi5AS5cQZxo&q=b
Django Version: 3.2.8
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

that error happend when I try to search with any words
[like this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz2PC.png)

views.py

```
class SearchView(ListView):
    template_name = 'travel_guide/view_list.html'
    paginate_by = 20
    count = 0

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['count'] = self.count or 0
        context['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.request
        query = request.GET.get('q', None)

        if query is not None:
            country_results        = country.objects.search(query)
            city_results      = city.objects.search(query)
            articles_results     = articles.objects.search(query)
            print(query)
            # combine querysets 
            queryset_chain = chain(
                    country_results,
                    city_results,
                    articles_results,
            )        
            qs = sorted(queryset_chain, 
                        key=lambda instance: instance.pk, 
                        reverse=True)
            self.count = len(qs) # since qs is actually a list
            return qs
        return country.objects.none()
```

HTML file

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% load class_name %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">

<div class='row title-row my-5'>
    <div class='col-12 py-0'>
        <h3 class='my-0 py-0'>{{ count }} results for <b>{{ query }}</b></h3>
    </div>
</div>


  {% for object in object_list %}
  {% with object|class_name as item %}
  {% if item == 'country' %}
    <div class="search-res">
    <div class='row s-color p-3 med-text'>
      <div class='col-12  '>
       <a href="{% url 'country_data' object.ckey  object.countryName %}">country data: {{ object.countryName }} </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    {% elif item == 'city' %}
    <div class='row s-color p-3 med-text'>
      <div class='col-12 '>
         <a href="{% url 'city_detail' object.cityID %}">city data: {{ object.cityName }}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    {% elif item == 'articles' %}
    <div class='row s-color p-3 med-text'>
      <div class='col-12 '>
        <a href="{% url 'articles_detail' object.id %}">article Item: {{ object.articleHeader }}</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  {% else %}
  <div class='row s-color p-3 med-text'>
    <div class='col-12 col-lg-8 offset-lg-4 '>
      <a href='{{ object.get_absolute_url }}'>{{ object }} | {{ object|class_name }}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
  {% endfor %}


{% endblock content %}
```

models.py

```
class customCountryQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def search(self, query=None):
        qs = self
        if query is not None:
            or_lookup = (Q(countryName__icontains=query) | 
                         Q(countryBrief__icontains=query)|
                         Q(cultures__icontains=query)
                        )
            qs = qs.filter(or_lookup).distinct() # distinct() is often necessary with Q lookups
        return qs

class country_Manager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return customCountryQuerySet(self.model, using = self._db)
    
    def search(self, query=None):
        return self.get_queryset().search(query=query)
```

and here the search form I use the name='q' to get the results of query

```
  <form class="d-flex index" method="GET" action="{% url 'search_view' %}">
  <div class="search-bar">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <img class="icon" alt="search icon" src="{% static 'travel_guide/img/search.svg' %}" />
    <input
      class="search-box"
      type="search"
      placeholder="Search for your way"  name="q"
    />
    <!-- <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">search</button> -->
  </div>
</form>
```

I expecting to display the results fine without theses errors I make a small research but I didn't find a helpful solution so I hope you help me .

Comment: Are you comparing two values using < (less than symbol)? One of those value is integer and other is string. You cannot compare an inter instance with string instance. That is the error.

Comment: @SarathR all models string and text fields I don't think so and I use the same code in different section and working well